# Heroku - Rails app gives 'No such app' when everything seems right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I have a new, Rails 6 app that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku.

Judging from the deploy log and the logs I'm getting with `heroku logs --tail` everything seems to work, but when I go to the deployed, herokuapp.com domain, I get the 'No such app' screen.

Here is the latest logs:

```
2021-11-19T13:45:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-11-19T13:45:11.060793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126085+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126103+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Zawgyi")
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126103+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] *  Min threads: 5
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126104+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] *  Max threads: 5
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126104+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] *  Environment: production
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126104+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] *   Master PID: 4
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126104+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] *      Workers: 2
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126127+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
2021-11-19T13:45:12.126133+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2021-11-19T13:45:13.203269+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:54150
2021-11-19T13:45:13.203334+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2021-11-19T13:45:13.207647+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (PID: 7) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
2021-11-19T13:45:13.209455+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (PID: 9) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
2021-11-19T13:45:13.336382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

And here's the puma config:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Which is the one recommended by Heroku in their documentation.

The `Procfile` is a simple one-liner:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

I also tried the heroku configuration by running `PORT=3000 heroku local` on my machine and it works wonderfully, but not on Heroku's platform :(

I'm using Rails 6.1.4.1 and ruby 3.0.2

Can you point me at where I could try to find the root of the problem?

Thank you,
Balint

Comment: All things google point to a "DNS issue" type of problems. Which just makes me wonder whether the `whatever.herokuapp.com` domain might have a typo when you're trying to hit it?

Comment: Probably not because I click the link that Heroku gives me as "Your app can be found at <link>".

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a transient issue. When I came back to the problem a few hours later, it just worked without me having to change anything.